# MISC cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I tried to add an item to my minecraft mod following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JZ7bnk3oiM.
The code is this:

```
public class ProvaMod implements ModInitializer {
    // This logger is used to write text to the console and the log file.
    // It is considered best practice to use your mod id as the logger's name.
    // That way, it's clear which mod wrote info, warnings, and errors.
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("modid");

    public static final Item IDK_IDK = new Item(new Item.Settings().group(ItemGroup.MISC));

    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
        Registry.register(Registry.ITEM, new Identifier("provamod", "idk_idk"), IDK_IDK);
    }
}
```

It Underlines red MISC (Line 7) and ITEM(Line 11) and gives this errors:

> MISC cannot be resolved or is not a field
> ITEM cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1.19.3 Registry must be replaced with Registries.
The code is:

```
public class ProvaMod implements ModInitializer {
    // This logger is used to write text to the console and the log file.
    // It is considered best practice to use your mod id as the logger's name.
    // That way, it's clear which mod wrote info, warnings, and errors.
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("modid");
    public static final Item Sapphire =Registry.register(Registries.ITEM, new Identifier("provamod","sapphire"), new Item(new FabricItemSettings()));

    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
    ItemGroupEvents.modifyEntriesEvent(ItemGroups.TOOLS).register(itemGroup ->  itemGroup.add(Sapphire) );
    }
}
```